# Action bar tabs with viewpager with different page layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi Im new in android and I want ask for help. Im creating new project in android studio and I use navigation Action bar tabs with viewpager. Android studio generate this code. I know work with one activity atc but now I want to learn work with swipe layouts with tabs. My question is: Is possible do more layouts with different items inside this? For example, now I have on every fragment one textview and when I swipe I see any text on every page. But I need for example on page(tab1) layout with textview, on tab2 I need layout edittext, on tab3 I need layout with image. Is this possible with this? Because I can change text but now I have the same layout for all tabs.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you can define 3 separate fragment classes. Then you can return them appropriately in `getItem` of your `SectionsPagerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new YourFragmentClass1();
        case 1:
            return new YourFragmentClass2();
        case 2:
            return new YourFragmentClass3();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind sharing the code for the getItem on SectionPagerAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Szymon's answer.

**Step 1** Delete the inner class `PlaceHolderFragment`
 **Step 2**: Create your fragment classes, with corresponding layouts. For example, `ImageViewFragment` (which extends Fragment of course) and then `image_view_fragment_layout`.
 **Step 3** Have `ImageViewFragment`'s `onCreateView` method inflate`image_view_fragment_layout`.

```
public ImageViewFragment extends Fragment {
  ...
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view_fragment_layout, 
                                                    container, false);
    return rootView;
  }
```

Follow these steps for as many tabs you want to add.

Then in the `getItem()` method follow Szymon's answer. Remember, the tab you want to appear first will be in position 0 and so on.

One more Important thing, in your getCount method:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
```

the number returned should reflect the number of tabs you have added.